# MYSQL Replace into never replace?

Tags: mysql, sql

I haven't really got a hang of how REPLACE INTO works.
From what i understand it will delete the row and insert the updated data if any of the values matches with the old rows values?

For example i have this table

```
+-------------+----------------+------+---------+
| name        | value          | city | address |
+-------------+----------------+------+---------+
| First book  | a value        | NY   | NULL    |
| second book | an other value | LA   | NULL    |
+-------------+----------------+------+---------+
```

now i want to change the city of second book and executes

```
REPLACE INTO book(name,value,city) VALUES ('second book','an other value','CA');
```

NOTE: Name and value is identical but mysql still inserts a new row?

```
+-------------+----------------+------+---------+
| name        | value          | city | address |
+-------------+----------------+------+---------+
| First book  | a value        | NY   | NULL    |
| second book | an other value | LA   | NULL    |
| second book | an other value | CA   | NULL    |
+-------------+----------------+------+---------+
```

Answer (score 3):

As you can read from [this link](http://blogs.coldbuffer.com/inserting-or-updating-records-using-mysql-replace):

> The result of the two SQL commands above can be achieved using a single query – using REPLACE INTO. REPLACE statement works the same way as the INSERT query. The only difference is the way they handle duplicate records. If there exists a unique index on a table and you attempted to insert a record that has a key value that’s previously inserted, that record will be deleted first and will insert the new record.

This means that it will update only if exists a unique key in the table, and you're trying to insert a value existing on this key. In thatc case, updates, else, makes the insert

Answer (score 1):

MySQL needs to know how to identify the row to `REPLACE`. The way to do that is to have a unique key that simply inserting the data would violate.

In your example, one solution is to put a `UNIQUE KEY` on `name`. Then your `REPLACE` would work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try using `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but be sure you have a constraint that `name` should be `unique key`.

```
INSERT INTO book (`name`, `value`, `city`)
VALUES ('second book', 'an other value', 'CA')
ON DUPLICATE KEY 
UPDATE `value` = 'an other value',
        `city` = 'CA'
```

**[See Example Link](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2006/05/29/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-and-summary-counters/)** 
**[INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE vs REPLACE INTO performance](http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2007/01/18/insert-on-duplicate-key-update-and-replace-into/)**